# Full authentication is required to access this resource in post request postman

Tags: spring, spring-boot

my postman output :--

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-10-19T10:34:26.171Z",
    "status": 401,
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "Full authentication is required to access this resource",
    "path": "/website/api/users/login"
}
```

my backend server :--

```
2020-10-19 16:04:26.168  WARN 8728 --- [io-8080-exec-14] c.website.website.jwt.JwtRequestFilter   : JWT Token does not contain auth string
```

Code:

```
package com.website.website.security;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.ToStringSerializer;
import com.website.website.jwt.CustomAuthProvider;
import com.website.website.jwt.JwtRequestFilter;
import com.website.website.jwt.MyAuthenticationEntryPoint;
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

import java.util.Date;


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private MyAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthProvider authProvider;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // configure AuthenticationManager so that it knows from where to load
        // user for matching credentials
        // Use BCryptPasswordEncoder
        auth.userDetailsService(jwtUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider);
    }


    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder objectMapperBuilder() {
        Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
        builder.serializerByType(ObjectId.class, new ToStringSerializer());
        builder.serializerByType(Date.class, new JsonDateSerializer());
        return builder;
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.cors();
        // We don't need CSRF for this example
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers( "/users/login","/users/addUser","/users/addCustomer", "/"
        ,"/v2/**","/swagger-ui.html","/webjars/**","/swagger-resources/**").permitAll().
                // all other requests need to be authenticated
                        anyRequest().authenticated().and().
                // make sure we use stateless session; session won't be used to
                // store user's state.
                        exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint).and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        // Add a filter to validate the tokens with every request
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/authenticate");
    }
}
```

Comment: my api :--http://localhost:8080/website/api/users/login

Comment: Can you add your postman request as well? Then it will be easy for the readers to help you in resolving the issue...

Comment: post:-http://localhost:8080/website/api/users/login

Answer (score 0):

In your postman the path is `"/website/api/users/login"` while it is not among the authorized paths. Changes `"/users/login"` with `"/website/api/users/login"`

Comment: why because   i deployed my project in apache tomcat server after that my path became localhost:8080/website and i have given in application properties like this server.servlet.context-path=/api and finally my path is -localhost:8080/website/api/

Comment: ok try to change your context-path with `/website/api`

Comment: tried but its not working pls help me out from this

Comment: @lkamal post:-localhost:8080/website/api/users/login

Comment: I read a little. And for the 401 error code it's an authentication problem. Check the body of your request.

Comment: checked and when i am running the local host its working properly and the above one is aslo local host but depolyed in apache .

Answer (score 0):

You have used WebSecurityCinfigurerAdapter annotation in the class file and starting Spring Boot 2.7.0, **WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter** is deprecated.